# How to boolean subtract an object's surface using a extruded plane?

Tags: objects, 3d-printing

I have an object and a plane as two separate entities like this:

[image]

[image]

I need to somehow invert the selected object onto the cylinder in order to make a boolean subtraction on the surface, so it look like this:

Because I'm prepping this file for a 3D print!

[image]

Comment: So are you asking because the Boolean modifier didn't work? I mean, why can't you just {Boolean} > {Difference} ?

Comment: Well I was just under the assumption that those tiny faces are pointing away from the surface so I guessed that the boolean modifier wouldn't work because of that

Comment: And yup I just tried it and it didn't work

Comment: if you have the original mesh before the curve modifier flip it and use the boolean

Comment: @Chebhou well the texture was never really a plane, it was originally a cylinder that I removed all the faces except the ones on the outside. Would I still be able to flip it?

Comment: guess you can't, but do you want to engrave it inward or just as it is placed in the image ? also you can flip the normals in edit mode to change the boolean result

Comment: @Chebhou how would I go about engraving it inwards?

Comment: to invert it : select on of the square faces ; select_similar ->perimeter ; set the transform manipulator to Normals, hit G and Z then Z again move the faces in word , then use the boolean